# Error in the Spotify web api callback php

Tags: php

I've tried using the Spotify-web-API by jwilsson as described here: https://github.com/jwilsson/spotify-web-api-php/blob/master/docs/examples/access-token-with-authorization-code-flow.md

I get the authorization to work, I receive the code in the redirected URL and am able to extract it, but I get the following error when I arrive at the callback page:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SpotifyWebAPI\SpotifyWebAPIAuthException:
>   Invalid redirect URI in
>   C:...\vendor\jwilsson\spotify-web-api-php\src\Request.php:49 Stack
>   trace: #0
>   C:...\vendor\jwilsson\spotify-web-api-php\src\Request.php(242):
>   SpotifyWebAPI\Request->parseBody(Object(stdClass), 400) #1
>   C:...\vendor\jwilsson\spotify-web-api-php\src\Request.php(99):
>   SpotifyWebAPI\Request->send('POST', 'https://account...',
>   'client_id=effb4...', Array) #2
>   C:...\vendor\jwilsson\spotify-web-api-php\src\Session.php(217):
>   SpotifyWebAPI\Request->account('POST', '/api/token', Array, Array) #3
>   C:...\callback.php(17):
>   SpotifyWebAPI\Session->requestAccessToken('AQB5DWrr3FQ_WVq...') #4
>   {main} thrown in
>   C:...\vendor\jwilsson\spotify-web-api-php\src\Request.php on line 49

The flow that I currently have is:
1) index.html
2) auth.php (to authenticate and redirect to callback.php)
3) callback.php (to get the access token and redirect to the page with my API calls "app.php")
4) app.php

pages of point 2 and 3 are registered in Spotify for the redirect URI

Comment: From the documentation you linked: "The REDIRECT_URI is the one you entered when creating the Spotify app, make sure it's an exact match." - did you check that? The error message sounds like there is a problem with it.

Comment: Yes, I even copy pasted it to be sure